# What is the correct way to combine a definition list with an ordered list?

Tags: html

I want to make an ordered definition list. Should I nest an `<ol>` in a `<dl>`, or the other way around?

i.e.

```
<h4>Bike Descriptions</h4>
<dl>
    <ol>
        <li>
            <dt>Giant Bikes</dt>
            <dd>Bikes that are very sturdy and reliable.</dd>
        </li>
        <li>
            <dt>Walmart Bikes</dt>
            <dd>Bikes that are crummy and heavy.</dd>
        </li>
    </ol>
</dl>
```

**Or** nest the `<dl>` within `<ol>` or even within each `<li>`?

[The docs don't seem to say.](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-dl-element)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [that documentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-dl-element), the only elements a `<dl>` may contain are `<dt>` and `<dd>`:

> **[Content model](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#element-dfn-content-model):**
>
> Zero or more groups each consisting of one or more [`dt`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-dt-element) elements followed by one or more [`dd`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-dd-element) elements, optionally intermixed with [script-supporting elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#script-supporting-elements-0).

Thus, your example code is invalid HTML. The only valid way to nest `dl` and `ol`/`ul` is in the order `ol`/`ul` > `li` > `dl` > `dt`+`dd`:

```html
<h4>Bike Descriptions</h4>    
<ol>
    <li>
        <dl>
            <dt>Giant Bikes</dt>
            <dd>Bikes that are very sturdy and reliable.</dd>
        </dl>
    </li>
    <li>
        <dl>
            <dt>Walmart Bikes</dt>
            <dd>Bikes that are crummy and heavy.</dd>
        </dl>
    </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: The spec now allows for one or more `<div>` elements as well.

Answer (score 2):

Your example is not a valid HTML tag. Perhaps you would like to do something like this.

```
<h4>Bike Descriptions</h4>    
<ul>
  <li>
    <dl>
      <dt>Giant Bikes</dt>
      <dd>Bikes that are very sturdy and reliable.</dd>
    </dl>
  </li>
  <li>
    <dl>
      <dt>Walmart Bikes</dt>
      <dd>Bikes that are crummy and heavy.</dd>
    </dl>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Then you can add style to your CSS to fix the layout.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think HTML has an element for an ordered definition list.

You might consider just using a `dl` element and then ordering its name-value groups how you'd like. (For example, the words in a dictionary typically aren't numbered and are just alphabetically ordered.)

If you really think you must number each name-value group of a `dl` element, then I think I'd likely disagree with you and beg you to reconsider, since I can't think of any examples where I'd consider doing so to be good style. If you can, feel free to share. But I tend to like to [keep it simple, stupid (KISS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle); I think less is often more; and probably [you aren't gonna need it (YAGNI)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it). However, if (even after reconsidering) you still want to do it, then you might consider [using CSS counters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Lists_and_Counters/Using_CSS_counters).

According to [WHATWG: HTML Standard: The `dl` element](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#the-dl-element):

> The order of the list of groups, and of the names and values within each group, may be significant.
>
> In order to annotate groups with [microdata](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/microdata.html#microdata) attributes, or other [global attributes](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#global-attributes) that apply to whole groups, or just for styling purposes, each group in a `dl` element can be wrapped in a `div` element. This does not change the semantics of the `dl` element.

Answer (score 0):

HTML doesn't have a way to markup an ordered definition list. I would suggest using a regular `<li>`, and the term defined marked with a `<dfn>` tag:

```
<ul>
  <li><dfn>Giant Bike</dfn> Bikes that are very sturdy and reliable.</li>
  <li><dfn>Walmart Bikes</dfn> Bikes that are crummy and heavy.</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [HTML spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-dl-element), a `<dl>` already accounts for ordering being important to some extend:

> The order of the list of groups, and of the names and values within each group, may be significant.

Also, from your example I don't thing order is the most important thing (i.e. it's not a step by step guide or anything like that).

In any case, if you think it is, I would suggest you use a regular `<ol>` and the [`<dfn>` tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dfn):

> The `<dfn>` HTML element is used to indicate the term being defined within the context of a definition phrase or sentence. The `<p>` element, the `<dt>`/`<dd>` pairing, or the `<section>` element which is the nearest ancestor of the `<dfn>` is considered to be the definition of the term.

According to this, I think the best way to represent an ordered list of definitions is like so:

```css
dfn {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

```html
<h4>Bike Descriptions</h4>

<ol>
  <li>
    <p>
      <dfn>Giant Bikes</dfn>
      Bikes that are very sturdy and reliable.
     </p>
  </li>
  
  <li>
    <p>
      <dfn>Walmart Bikes</dfn>
      Bikes that are crummy and heavy.
    </p>
  </li>
</ol>
```